# Yahoo finance Flash vars for interactive chart

Tags: flash, api, yahoo-finance

I'm using Yahoo Finance interactive flash chart (code below).
Does anyone knows the flash Vars all posiible Properties?
(like: compare= | indicator=volume%2Bmfi | charttype=area | and so...)

thank you =)

```
<object id="yfi_chart_swf" width="824" height="716" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://l.yimg.com/bm/lib/fi/common/p/d/static/swf/2.0.253765/2.0.0/en-US/largechart.swf" style="visibility: visible; height: 716px;">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="flashvars" value="sigDevEnabled=true&changeSymbolEnabled=false&state=symbol=YHOO;range=my;compare=;indicator=volume%2Bmfi;charttype=area;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined;">
</object>
```